# Concatenate strings inside bash script (different behaviour from shell)

Tags: linux, bash, string

I'm trying some staff that is working perfectly when I write it in the regular shell, but when I include it in a bash script file, it doesn't.
First example:

```
m=`date +%m`
m_1=$((m-1))
echo $m_1
```

This gives me the value of the last month (actual minus one), but doesn't work if its executed from a script.

Second example:

```
m=6
m=$m"t"
echo m
```

This returns "6t" in the shell (concatenates $m with "t"), but just gives me "t" when executing from a script.

I assume all these may be answered easily by an experienced Linux user, but I'm just learning as I go.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-check your syntax.

Your first code snippet works either from **command line**, from **bash** and from **sh** since your syntax is valid sh. In my opinion you probably have typos in your script file:

```
~$ m=`date +%m`; m_1=$((m-1)); echo $m_1
4
~$ cat > foo.sh
m=`date +%m`; m_1=$((m-1)); echo $m_1
^C
~$ bash foo.sh
4
~$ sh foo.sh
4
```

The same can apply to the other snippet with corrections:

```
~$ m=6; m=$m"t"; echo $m
6t
~$ cat > foo.sh
m=6; m=$m"t"; echo $m
^C
~$ bash foo.sh
6t
~$ sh foo.sh
6t
```

Comment: Ok, sorry, I tried with "cat" and it's working perfectly, as you say. Maybe there was some problem with my editor (Crimson). Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Rorro; good to know. You may consider mark the answer as valid. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the first line of your script is

```
#!/bin/bash
```

rather than

```
#!/bin/sh
```

Bash will only enable its extended features if explicitly run as `bash`.  If run as `sh`, it will operate in POSIX compatibility mode.

Comment: Yes, first line is "#!/bin/bash", I forgot to say, and it's not working either...

Comment: check my answer. It's not an issue with bash/sh since its all valid sh syntax. The OP needs to review any typo he may have done in his scripts. The code he posts is valid (except a typo in his second snippet of code)

Comment: @hmontoliu: I figured this to be a typo in the post -- the OP claims the output of the second snippet to be `t`, not `m`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it works fine for me in a script, and on the terminal.
Second of all, your last line, `echo m` will just output "m". I think you meant "$m"..

Comment: Yes, I ment $m, my mistake :D . Anyway, hmontoliu's answer was enough. I tried creating the script from the shell and it worked. As I said, it could any mistake using a different editor.